# Finding most queried items in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server database which has table consisting of tickers. Something like

```
Ticker | description
-------+-------------
USDHY  | High yield 
USDIG  | Investment grade  ...
```

Now we have a lot of other tables which has data corresponding to these tickers (time series). We want to able to create a report which can show us which of these tickers are more queried for and which not not queried for at all. This can allow us to selectively run some procedures for the tickers which are more frequently used and ignore the others on a regular basis.

Is there some way to achieve this in SQL, any report which could generate this stat over a period of time say n-months.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can create a trigger that logs it in another table when a record is accessed. You can then run your report off of this other table. However, keep in mind there will be some performance overhead as the trigger will have to execute every time the data is queried

Comment: Trigger for select? I would advise SQL Server Audit or Extended Events. Are this records accessed from application? That would be another option.

Comment: I would absolutely use the application to log queries to a log table.   If you can't use the application, I guess you can look into using a third party transaction log reader, but if it were me, I'd tell my boss the place for this logic is in the application.   ...actually I wouldn't have to tell him because he'd already know.   : )

Comment: @DavidCram There are no triggers for `select`. Only for `update`, `insert` and `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like no answers so far. As I mentioned, one possibility is to use Extended Events like below:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TestTableSelectLog]
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed (
WHERE [statement] LIKE '%SELECT%TestTable%' --Capure all selects from TestTable
  AND [statement] NOT LIKE '%XEStore%' --filter extended event queries
  AND [statement] NOT LIKE '%fn_xe_file_target_read_file%'),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed (
WHERE [statement] LIKE '%SELECT%TestTable%'
  AND [statement] NOT LIKE '%XEStore%'
  AND [statement] NOT LIKE '%fn_xe_file_target_read_file%')
ADD TARGET package0.event_file (SET FILENAME=N'C:\Temp\TestTableSelectLog.xel');--log to file

ALTER EVENT SESSION [TestTableSelectLog] ON SERVER STATE=START;--start capture
```

You can then select from file using `sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file`:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    Ticker varchar(10),
    [Description] nvarchar(100)
)

SELECT * FROM TestTable

SELECT *, CAST(event_data AS XML) AS 'event_data_XML'  
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\Temp\TestTableSelectLog*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

The `SELECT` statement should be captured.

Extended Events can be also configured from GUI (Management/Extended Events/Sessions in Management Studio).

Comment: This logs all procedures and queries which have accessed the table, nice! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: A couple more questions if you could: what will be the performance impact of having this in place, in general? I assume some routine procedures and queries will be slower because the d/b needs to save everything in a log file?

Comment: If filter is set correctly (`WHERE` clause in `ADD EVENT`), only records matching predicate are logged in file. I would not expect noticeable performance impact however some operations (filtering all queries) must be performed.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, thanks. Does the event sqlserver.sql_statement_completed also captures functions and views which use the table?

Comment: Yes, since querying view is also statement.